# How to connect to remote database with neo4j-admin?

Tags: docker, neo4j, remote-access

I'm running Neo4j in a docker container and would like to use the neo4j-admin installed locally to connect to the database running in the container. Is it possible and if yes, how?

I know that I could run the neo4-admin tool directly in the container, but that's not what I want to.

Is there any possibility to pass the address and credentials to neo4-admin like `neo4j-admin -a <my-ip>:<my-port> -u <my-user> -p <my-pwd>` or similiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `neo4j-admin` CLI is only available locally. But the `cypher-shell` can be used remotely.